# ListItem with non-ListItems nested children?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I really need a component in React like those you have on your website :

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5AO8.png)

What I need is a band with a title on it and a button on the right.
When you click on this button, it opens a dropdown component on which you can call other component (like on your website, there are the source code, me I want to put other components in)

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rgxT.png)

I need a dropdown component that makes the full width of the app bar, like on material-ui website when you click to see the source code. I need to put in other components I created, so an Icon Menu can't fit (you can only have MenuItems as children).

To be more clear, a ListItem would be perfect, but the nested items can only be List Items too... So i'm blocked.

```
<List>
    <ListItem
        primaryText="Profile 1"
        initiallyOpen={false}
        primaryTogglesNestedList={true}
        key={1}
        nestedItems={[
            <ListItem
                 key={1-1}
                 primaryText="I am a list item component..."
                 disabled={true}
                 primaryTogglesNestedList={true}
            />
        ]}
    />
</List>
```

The code I would like to put in my ListItem would be :

```
                <TextField key={this.props.index} name="profileType" hintText="Type de profil" fullWidth={true} value={this.props.state.profileAgir.type.libelle} onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
                <br />
                <div>
                    <h2>Entités de couverture</h2>
                    <MyRGOCovTree onCheck={this.onCheckCov} key={this.props.index} multiple={true}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h2>Entités d'exécution</h2>
                    <MyRGOExeTree onCheck={this.onCheckExe} key={this.props.index} multiple={true}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h2>Entités juridiques</h2>
                    <MyEnttTree onCheck={this.onCheckEJ} key={this.props.index} />
                </div> 
                {this.props.state.cube === "AGIR" &&
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <h2>Filière</h2>
                        <Tree onCheck={this.onCheckFil} key={this.props.index} className="myCls" showLine showIcon={false} checkable defaultExpandedKeys={['ALL']} selectable={false} >
                            <TreeNode title="All" key="ALL">
                                <TreeNode title="Risques" key="Risques" >
                                    <TreeNode title="Risques Opérationnels" key="Risques Opérationnels"/>
                                    <TreeNode title="Risques de Marché" key="Risques de Marché"/>
                                    <TreeNode title="Risques de Crédit" key="Risques de Crédit"/>
                                </TreeNode>
                                <TreeNode title="Juridique" key="Juridique" />
                                <TreeNode title="Finance" key="Finance" >
                                    <TreeNode title="Comptabilité" key="Comptabilité"/>
                                    <TreeNode title="Réglementaire" key="Réglementaire"/>
                                    <TreeNode title="Autres" key="Autres"/>
                                </TreeNode>
                                <TreeNode title="Fiscalité" key="Fiscalité" />
                                <TreeNode title="Ressources Humaines" key="Ressources Humaines" />
                                <TreeNode title="Systèmes d'Information" key="Systèmes d'Information" >
                                    <TreeNode title="Systèmes d'Information" key="S/Systèmes d'Information"/>
                                    <TreeNode title="Sécurité des Systèmes d'Information" key="Sécurité des Systèmes d'Information"/>
                                </TreeNode>
                                <TreeNode title="Conformité" key="Conformité" />
                                <TreeNode title="Immobilier" key="Immobilier" />
                                <TreeNode title="Achats" key="Achats" />
                                <TreeNode title="Communication" key="Communication" />
                            </TreeNode>
                        </Tree>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p> Données issues de la vue V_DWH_REF_FILIERE en DEV</p>
                        {this.props.filieresError && <div><i><b>{this.props.filieresError.message}</b></i></div>}
                        {this.props.filieresItems.length ? ( <MyFiliereTree key={this.props.index} onCheck={this.props.onCheck} items={this.props.filieresItems} checkedKeys={this.props.state.filieres}/> ) : 'loading...'}
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h2>Processus</h2>
                        <MyProcTree onCheck={this.onCheckProc} key={this.props.index} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h2>Confidentialité</h2>
                        <MyConfTree onCheck={this.onCheckConf} key={this.props.index} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h2>Application</h2>
                        <MyAppTree onCheck={this.onCheckApp} key={this.props.index} style={{paddingBot:20}} />
                    </div>
                </div>
                }
```

So it's pretty big and full of different components.
Imagine the example I gave you on the material-ui website, but when you click on the bar you don't have the source code that appears but my components, like a  !

If anyone have a solution

Comment: did you even bother to check the website? http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/app-bar

Comment: @azium of course I did, but how get a dropdown component when you click on the right button is not explained

Comment: its explained right here http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/icon-menu

Comment: @azium I don't need an Icon Menu but a dropdown component that makes the full width of the app bar, like when you click to see the source code, you see ?

Comment: @azium Moreover, with a IconMenu you can only put MenuItems on it, but I need to put other components I created

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems not possible with the React Components so I made it by myself with Paper.

```
    dropDownTrees = () => {
        if (this.state.drop === "close") this.setState({drop: "open"});
        else this.setState({drop: "close"});
    }

    render () {
        console.log(this.state);
        return (
                <Paper zDepth={2}>
                    <div className='row'>
                        <Subheader>{this.props.label}</Subheader>
                        <IconButton onTouchTap={this.dropDownTrees}><Add/></IconButton>
                    </div>
                    {this.state.drop === 'open' && 
                    <div style={{marginLeft: 20}}>
                        <TextField key={this.props.index} name="profileType" hintText="Type de profil" fullWidth={true} value={this.props.state.profileAgir.type.libelle} onChange={this.props.onChange}/>
                        <br />
                        <div>
                            <h2>Entités de couverture</h2>
                            <MyRGOCovTree onCheck={this.onCheckCov} key={this.props.index} multiple={true}/>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h2>Entités d'exécution</h2>
                            <MyRGOExeTree onCheck={this.onCheckExe} key={this.props.index} multiple={true}/>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <h2>Entités juridiques</h2>
                            <MyEnttTree onCheck={this.onCheckEJ} key={this.props.index} />
                        </div> 
                        {this.props.state.cube === "AGIR" &&
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    <h2>Filière</h2>
                                    <Tree onCheck={this.onCheckFil} key={this.props.index} className="myCls" showLine showIcon={false} checkable defaultExpandedKeys={['ALL']} selectable={false} >
                                        <TreeNode title="All" key="ALL">
                                            <TreeNode title="Risques" key="Risques" >
                                                <TreeNode title="Risques Opérationnels" key="Risques Opérationnels"/>
                                                <TreeNode title="Risques de Marché" key="Risques de Marché"/>
                                                <TreeNode title="Risques de Crédit" key="Risques de Crédit"/>
                                            </TreeNode>
                                            <TreeNode title="Juridique" key="Juridique" />
                                            <TreeNode title="Finance" key="Finance" >
                                                <TreeNode title="Comptabilité" key="Comptabilité"/>
                                                <TreeNode title="Réglementaire" key="Réglementaire"/>
                                                <TreeNode title="Autres" key="Autres"/>
                                            </TreeNode>
                                            <TreeNode title="Fiscalité" key="Fiscalité" />
                                            <TreeNode title="Ressources Humaines" key="Ressources Humaines" />
                                            <TreeNode title="Systèmes d'Information" key="Systèmes d'Information" >
                                                <TreeNode title="Systèmes d'Information" key="S/Systèmes d'Information"/>
                                                <TreeNode title="Sécurité des Systèmes d'Information" key="Sécurité des Systèmes d'Information"/>
                                            </TreeNode>
                                            <TreeNode title="Conformité" key="Conformité" />
                                            <TreeNode title="Immobilier" key="Immobilier" />
                                            <TreeNode title="Achats" key="Achats" />
                                            <TreeNode title="Communication" key="Communication" />
                                        </TreeNode>
                                    </Tree>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <p> Données issues de la vue V_DWH_REF_FILIERE en DEV</p>
                                    {this.props.filieresError && <div><i><b>{this.props.filieresError.message}</b></i></div>}
                                    {this.props.filieresItems.length ? ( <MyFiliereTree key={this.props.index} onCheck={this.props.onCheck} items={this.props.filieresItems} checkedKeys={this.props.state.filieres}/> ) : 'loading...'}
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <h2>Processus</h2>
                                    <MyProcTree onCheck={this.onCheckProc} key={this.props.index} />
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <h2>Confidentialité</h2>
                                    <MyConfTree onCheck={this.onCheckConf} key={this.props.index} />
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <h2>Application</h2>
                                    <MyAppTree onCheck={this.onCheckApp} key={this.props.index} style={{paddingBot:20}} />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    }                   
                </Paper>

       );
    }
}
```

My CSS to make the Subheader and the IconButton side by side

```
.row{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
}
```

Before touching the icon button :

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3e46.png)

After touching the icon button (opens the "dropdown" div) :

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1yA8.png)

Works perfectly. (don't forget to add drop:'close' on your state)

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can just make this using flexbox and the 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/view-column' and material-ui icon menu

e.g

```
<div className='toolbar'>
        <div>
            <IconMenu
                iconButtonElement={<IconButton><ViewColum/></IconButton>}
                anchorOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top'}}
                targetOrigin={{horizontal: 'left', vertical: 'top'}}
            >
                <MenuItem primaryText="Refresh" />
                <MenuItem primaryText="Send feedback" />
                <MenuItem primaryText="Settings" />
                <MenuItem primaryText="Help" />
                <MenuItem primaryText="Sign out" />
            </IconMenu>
        </div>
        <div>
            <span> {'Title'} </span>
        </div>
    </div>

.toolbar{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  background-color: your-color
}
```

Play around with that ?

Comment: Thanks @Davet for answering.
The thing is that I need a dropdown component that makes the full width of the app bar, like on material-ui website when you click to see the source code.
Moreover, with a IconMenu you can only put MenuItems as children, but I need to put in other components I created